# PostgreSQL - Grant read/write privileges to user in schema only

Tags: postgresql

I want to create a user `team` with write access restricted to a single schema `team` and readonly access to `public`.

Here's what I've tried:

```sql
-- create user and schema
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS team;
CREATE USER team WITH ENCRYPTED PASSWORD 'xxxxxxxx';

-- team schema write privileges
GRANT CREATE ON DATABASE analytics TO team;
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA team TO team;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA team TO team;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR USER team IN SCHEMA team GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON TABLES TO team;

-- public schema read only privileges
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA public TO team;
GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO team;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR USER team IN SCHEMA public GRANT SELECT ON TABLES TO team;
```

Test data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.test_table AS SELECT 1 col1; -- should be denied for team user
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS team.test_table AS SELECT 2 col1; -- should be allowed for team user

SELECT * FROM team.test_table ; -- should be allowed for team user
SELECT * FROM public.existing_table ; -- should be allowed for team user
```

The problem is, whilst connected to the db as `team`, a `SELECT * FROM team.test_table` raised a permission error (as well as for `public.test_table` for that user).

I'm clearly missing something, I don't know what that is...

Comment: Don't the role `team` must have `create `privilege on database ?

Comment: @Philippe didn't work unfortunately...

Comment: `ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR USER team` seems wrong if you didn't run those `CREATE` statements as `team`.

Comment: @Bergi you're right it should be `GRANT ALL` unfortunately no luck... i've edited description to reflect changes

Comment: Did the tables get created and if so by whom? What is the permission error? What does, in `psql`, `\dp <table_name>` show? Add as update to question.

Answer (score 1):

The table creator should be mentioned while granting default privileges.
ex- Suppose you are creating table with user XYZ then default privileges statement be like,

ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR ROLE XYZ IN SCHEMA team GRANT ALL ON TABLES TO team;

For public read only you can revoke permissions from user team

REVOKE CREATE ON SCHEMA public FROM team;

REVOKE ALL ON ALL TABLEs IN SCHEMA public FROM team;

GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO team;